# header inside a class c++ and scope

Tags: c++

I have some code

```
class anyClass
{ 
    #include"headerWithSomeFunction.h"
}
```

and in headerWithSomeFunction.h

```
#pragma once
void SomeFunction(){};
```

Is this the same as

```
class anyClass
{ 
    void SomeFunction(){};
}
```

Or does this have dangerous scope implications.  I am making my code more readable.
Thank you

Comment: Yes, it is the same.

Comment: It makes for very hard to maintain code, and can be unreliable if you used this extensively.  The preprocessor step (which is what processes `#include` directives) happens before the C++ compiler parses the code.

Comment: _"Or does this have dangerous scope implications."_ Of course it does. What particular problem are you trying to resolve with such idiom?

Comment: It’s the same, in the sense that chopping off your foot with and without morphine is the same. The end effect is no different, but by using headers you’re going to be in a lot more pain.

Comment: It is not the same.  It is the same only if the header is included only once.

Answer (score 2):

> Is this the same

It can potentially be the same. In this minimal example, it is the same. But if the file is included from elsewhere first, then the #pragma once would cause the inclusion to be empty within this file and thus not the same. If you remove the pragma, *then* it would be the same in effect.

Despite the name "header", files included with the pre-processor are not technically limited to being at the "head" of the file.

> I am making my code more readable.

Then I suggest to not include headers inside of a class definition.

In fact, I suggest to only include header files at the global namespace scope. This is a widespread convention, and strict adherence to this convention allows reader of a header file to understand contents of that header without knowing where it is included into.

Meaning of declarations and definitions of a header file should not depend on where the file is included into. A declaration in a block scope, or inside a class definition has a very different meaning than a declaration at the namespace scope.

Comment: I assumed "readable" for the sake of the code snippet.  Not readable as a general practice.

Comment: @Eljay that's not my interpretation, but I'm now wondering which version they are suggesting to be more readable.

Comment: I can not infer which version of the code is "before"  and which is "after"

Comment: Answering a XY problem with X is probably not that helpful.